# What is such a weird string?

Tags: string, symbols

I found such string in a forum, which is across several lines with simple symbols in only one line.

I tried to Google the source of it, but Google responds with `400` error:

```
400. That's an error
Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.
That's all we know.
```

ฏ๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎ฏฏด้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็้็็็ฏ๎็็็็็็oด้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็้้

Comment: Whut? Never seen anything like it. I think it is somekind of strange font rather then strings. tried putting it in lmgtfy which generates an insanely long url.

Comment: It's a character from another language whose name I forgot. It's perfectly normal and for space reasons it is often not rendered completely

Comment: @Macro A. How to explain the Google 400 error?